# PHP - parse xml to nested json

Tags: php, nested, parsexml

I am trying to parse a xml to a nested json structure with php.

This is my test script:

```
$json_drives = array();

foreach($drives->DR as $dr){
    $current_drive = array();
    $current_drive['id'] = $dr->ID;
    $current_drive['name'] = $dr->NAME->D;
    $json_drives[] = $current_drive;
}
echo("Finished");

// Parse and save
$f = json_encode($json_drives);
file_put_contents('test12345.json', $f);
```

I get a structure like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": {
            "0": "1"
        },
        "name": {
            "0": "Name 1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "0": "2"
        },
        "name": {
            "0": "Name 2"
        }
    },
    // ...
 ]
```

But I dont want the keys "id" and "name" to be nested. It should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1"
        "name": "Name 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2"
        "name": "Name 2"
    },
    // ...
]
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: Do you have a sample XML to test with?

Comment: It would help if you showed us a sample of the XML you are processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON's "drive" objects will always have this structure:

```
"id": {
    "0": "Some ID"
},
"name": {
    "0": "Some name"
}
```

You can use:

```
$current_drive['id'] = ((array) $dr->ID)[0];
$current_drive['name'] = ((array) $dr->NAME->D)[0];
```